# Parsing string to string array using regular expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have such string: any characters (except \n) combined with \n, \n could be anywhere in the string and repeats 0 or more times

```
var input = "\nabc\n\n";
```

The expected output is:

```
var output = ['\n', 'abc', '\n', '\n']
```

I can use input.split('\n') to make the string into an array, but in this case I'll lose \n, actually I need both \n and any other characters.

Comment: Which language are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be more appropriate.

```
> var s = "\nabc\n\n";
> s.match(/\n|[^\n]+/g)
[ '\n',
  'abc',
  '\n',
  '\n' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
console.log(input.match(/\n|\w+/g)); // ["↵", "abc", "↵", "↵"]
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, the \w doesn't match special characters such as *()&^%$#@!~ but I need these characters

Answer (score 0):

```
(\\n)|(\w+)
```

Try this.grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/11

Comment: Thanks! But \w doesn't match special characters such as *();+?/,.<>|\%$#@!~

Answer (score 0):

You can split with multiline anchors.

```
input.split(/^|$/gm)
```

You will get:

```
["
", "abc", "
", "
"]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using `(?=\n)`? As this wouldn't actual capture the `\n` character